# 2 Flot Charts with same grid size

Tags: jquery, grid, flot

I have a site with 2 flot graphs. graph 1 has (f.ex.) 3 y-axis on the left hand side and 2 on the right hand. the second plot below the first one has just one y-axis. how can i adjust both plots, so that the grid´s are the same width? i use

```
        GridWidth1 = flotGraph.width();
        GridHeight1 = flotGraph.height();
```

to get the width and height of the first plot and i want to take this values to adjust the second plot. but it doesn´t work. does anybody has a clue about...?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question whether you want the graphs to line-up (i.e. the left-side of the grid should line up vertically or the top of the grid should line up horizontally) or whether you want the grids to be the same size (i.e. the vertical lines within the graphs should be the same width apart).

Regardless though, your best bet to make them look "the same" is to use the axis options `labelWidth`, `labelHeight`, and `reserveSpace` (see the [API](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) for details).

To quote from that page:

> "labelWidth" and "labelHeight" specifies a fixed size of the tick
>   labels in pixels. They're useful in case you need to align several
>   plots. "reserveSpace" means that even if an axis isn't shown, Flot
>   should reserve space for it - it is useful in combination with
>   labelWidth and labelHeight for aligning multi-axis charts.

So what you'd want to do is specify the same axes on your second graph, but just don't show them.

Comment: "...whether you want the graphs to line-up..."
That´s exactly what i want to do. The easiest way is to have at this link: [http://ipad.glassglobal.com/fas/graph/]

Both grids have a black 2px border and I want to have them on the left and right hand site the same position.